# Loop over groupby iteration to Excel

Tags: python, excel, iteration

I have a dataframe detailing information on store location and revenue. I would like to iterate this information, but break it down by location and machine number, and then export this information to excel. My current dataframe looks like this

```
  Location     Machine Number Net Funds Net Revenue
0 Location 1   123456         123       76
1 Location 1   325462         869       522
2 Location 1   569183         896       234
3 Location 2   129756         535       542 
4 Location 2   234515         986       516 
5 Location 2   097019         236       512 
6 Location 3   129865         976       251
```

Ideally, the output would look something like this

```
Machine Number    Net Funds     Net Revenue
Location 1
123456            123           76
325462            869           522
269183            896           234
Machine Number    Net Funds     Net Revenue
Location 2
129756            535           542
234515            986           516
097019            236           512
Machine Number    Net Funds     Net Revenue
Location 3
129865            976           251
```

While I have been able to iterate this data into the format that I like using

```
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(group)
```

I cannot call it to xlsxwriter.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The excel result should be on a single sheet?  With repeated column headers?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, ideally it is in one sheet with repeated headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use **to_csv** to create a csv string, then adjust the column headers. You can open the CSV file in Excel.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Location','Machine Number','Net Funds','Net Revenue']
lst = [
['Location 1','123456',123, 76],
['Location 1','325462',869,522],
['Location 1','569183',896,234],
['Location 2','129756',535,542],
['Location 2','234515',986,516],
['Location 2','097019',236,512],
['Location 3','129865',976,251]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)

loclst = df['Location'].unique().tolist()

cc = ""
for loc in loclst:
   dfl = df[df['Location']==loc][cols[1:]]
   cc += ','.join(cols[1:]) + '\n' + loc+',,\n' + dfl.to_csv(index=False, header=False)

print(cc)
with open('out.csv','w') as f:
   f.write(cc.replace('\r\n','\n'))
```

Output  (out.csv)

```
Machine Number,Net Funds,Net Revenue
Location 1,,
123456,123,76
325462,869,522
569183,896,234
Machine Number,Net Funds,Net Revenue
Location 2,,
129756,535,542
234515,986,516
097019,236,512
Machine Number,Net Funds,Net Revenue
Location 3,,
129865,976,251
```